# CSS Grid not expanding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I created a simple React app using Create-React-App and just working on the App.js file for now.

My App.js and App.module.css files look like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

As you can see, the 2 lines of CSS should create something like the Pancake Stack (no. 4) - https://1linelayouts.glitch.me/

But it creates something like:
[image]

I cannot understand what is wrong over here?
I just want a small header and full width container with a small footer.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: check the height of the `.App`, maybe it is not taking up the viewport height

Comment: why do I have to specify that?
shouldn't it work without it? I am confused.

Comment: on the website you've linked, they have an example which you can access if you click "Explore on CodePen", perhaps that will provide you some insight

Comment: Did you try with <div> instead of <p>? I hope you gave hight: 100vh to the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `height: 100%` for your parent div, without it grid actually do not know what height it can use for auto and take the minimum required space.